# Notificações sobre a qualidade das respostas

Tags: suporte, notificações

Nunca tinha percebido notificações nas respostas, vi pela primeira vez no Ask Different:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Então, pesquisei por `hasnotice:1 is:a` no Stack Overflow e encontrei:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Aqui no SOpt [não achei nada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasnotice%3A1%20is%3Aa)...

Finalmente, fui no Metão e encontrei [What are these notices under my post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165006/185667), que fala dos seis tipos de aviso que um post pode ter: *Wiki Answer*, *citation needed*, *current event*, *insufficient explanation*, *bounty*, *locked*.

As mensagens mostradas acima corresponderiam a *explicação insuficiente* e *citação requerida*. Como proceder por aqui? Se encontrarmos alguma resposta que mereça um aviso desses é só sinalizar para atenção dos moderadores? Isso está traduzido? <sup><sub>(grande pergunta!)</sub></sup>

Comment: Fiquei na dúvida se criar a meta-tag `[avisos-no-post]` (ou similar)...

Comment: Que eu saiba, temos uma. Fica na pergunta, mas se refere à resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349/material-em-portugu%C3%AAs-para-iniciantes-em-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38177/74 Não sei se usei bem o recurso nesse caso.

Comment: Ahnnn, foste experimentar com o aviso mais localizado de todos... Como o AP diz na resposta que outros devs tiveram o mesmo problema e que sumiu no mesmo dia, acho que tem cabimento notificar que é um evento mutante.

Comment: Eu preferia o aviso na pergunta, mas o problema descrito na lá pode ocorrer em outras situações também. Achei que podia ficar confuso o aviso ali. Seria legal se a pergunta tivesse outra resposta mais completa (e mais votada).

Comment: É, saia-justa. [Este comentário da Anna Lear](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107269/what-does-the-current-event-post-notice-mean#comment275898_107292) me deixa na dúvida. Chegou a ler aquele tópico? Na verdade, que a própria Anna tenha perguntado e que a situação seja a mesma até hoje sem ter havido ajuste na frase (?)...

Comment: Não tinha visto. Isto também é interessante: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107269/what-does-the-current-event-post-notice-mean#comment275861_107271

Comment: Grande, muito bom esse. . . . Pensamento randômico: será que ao sermos "localizados" não teríamos liberdade de adaptar/melhorar algumas coisas (textuais) que ficam emperradas lá nos feature-request do Metão?

Comment: Acho que sim. Até que eles mudem a versão em inglês e a nossa tradução suma :)

Comment: *LOL2much, go, go localization team!*